# upgradation of application from net framework 2.0 to 4.5

Tags: asp.net, .net, .net-framework-version

We have an application running on .net framework 2.0,Now we need to upgrade that to .net framework 4.5.
How can i do that?could you please suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

You can update your Target framework directly from your solution

1. Click on the project > then click on properties
2. Click on the dropdown Target framework.
3. Choose the one you need[image]

To Make it work, you need to install the required frameworks too.

Try this link
https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=30653

Comment: Are you sure it will not affect my Project. One more question if i am committing this code to svn then the server also need to have the latest framework version right?

Comment: Yes, you are going to need to install the framework in the server if you are hosting 
 it in a server. You also need to setup the development environment too.

Comment: Thanks..... I Have one query in my server i don't have any setup of visual studio we hosted that sites in that server still the sites are running fine  how?